# complexity of a recursive function inside another recursive function

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I can't figure out the solution of this excercise:

Calculate the complexity of f(g(n))+g(f(n)) with g and f defined as follows:

```
int f(int x) {
 if (x<=1) return 2;
 int a = g(x) + 2*f(x/2);
 return 1+ x + 2*a;
}

int g(int x) {
int b=0;
 if (x<=1) return 5;
     for (int i=1, i<=x*x;i++)
         b+=i;
 return b + g(x-1);
}
```

could anyone explain me how to get to the solution?

Comment: Does your textbook or class material explain how to get the solution? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Complexity of `g` can simply be computed...

Comment: Better to write `2 * f(x/2)` instead of `f(x/2)+f(x/2)`.

Comment: @TypeIA
I have to calculate the recurrence of time and result for both functions, but i don't know how.
The time recurrence for f(x) is :k*n^2 + 2Tf(n/2) (why?) so it's O(n^3) (why?).
And result recurrence is k*n^4 + 4Rf(n/4) (why?) so it's O(n^5) (why?).
Does the same thing for the g function  and then calculates f(g(n))+g(f(n)).
The solution is O(n^15),but i can't figure out why.

Comment: by "complexity" do you mean that of the *output* or *execution time*?

Comment: execution time.

Comment: @DumbWrench Who told you that the solution is **O(n^15)** ?

Comment: My textbook....

Comment: Apologies as I failed to read your question properly; I have edited my answer to include full workings which give the same result as your textbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two separate steps to solving this problem. Firstly we must look at the *time* complexity of each function, and then the *output* complexity.

---

**Time complexity**

Since `g` is self-contained, let's look at it first.

The work done in `g` consists of:

- `x^2` executions of a loop
- A recursive call with parameter `x - 1`

Hence one might write the time complexity recurrence relation as (using upper-case to distinguish it from the original function)

[image]

To solve it, repeatedly self-substitute to give a summation. This is the sum of the squares of natural numbers from 6 to `x`:

[image]

Where in the last step we used a standard result. And thus, since `a` is a constant:

> [image]

Next, `f`:

- One call to `g(x)`
- One recursive call with parameter `x / 2`
- Some constant amount of work

[image]

Using a similar method:

[image]

Applying the stopping condition:

[image]

Thus:

[image]

Since the exponential term `2^(-x^3)` vanishes:

> [image]

---

**Output complexity**

This is basically the same process as above, with slightly different recursion relations. I'll skip the details and just state the results (using lower case for output functions):

[image]

---

Thus the final time complexity of `f(g(n)) + g(f(n))` is:

> [image]
>
> Which matches the result given by your source.

Comment: What does "output complexity" mean?

Comment: @ruakh yeah I should have clarified - the growth complexity of the functions' return value with respect to the input variable `x`.

Comment: Oh, I see. I think you've misunderstood the term "complexity". "Complexity" refers to the amount of resources needed for something. For example, we might say that an algorithm has a time complexity of 2‌ operations, where  is the input. As you know, we typically talk about complexity in terms of asymptotic growth rates (by using Landau notation); but when we talk about other things in terms of asymptotic growth rates, we don't use the term "complexity" for that.

Comment: @ruakh thanks for the correction but I'm not sure I understand your explanation - what differentiates "complexity in terms of asymptotic growth rates" from "other things"? I've seen countless examples of "growth complexity" and "asymptotic growth rate" being interchangeably used, and also for all kinds of quantities, not just time.

Comment: There are many kinds of resource -- time, storage, logic gates, etc. -- and therefore many kinds of "complexity". But a function's return-value isn't a resource it consumes, so it doesn't make sense to say that (for example) the function  :  ↦ 2 has an "output complexity" of 2 or (). Rather, we say that  ∈ (). If you've really seen "growth complexity" in reference to things other than complexity, then -- that's lame, but now you know better. :-)